# Define focus event on content agrregation of "sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout"

Tags: sapui5

I am new to jquery stuff and have no idea about how to define focus event on sapUI5 controls. I am using 'content' aggregation of 'sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout', there I need to perform some action whenever user hover or focus on specific content in that vertical Layout. I tried to find focus or hover event for verticalLayout content only but couldn't found it, but I ma sure there must be some jQueryevent that I can use. But I don't know how to use it. Please help me in getting this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share some code of what you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

I understood what to do, actually I was adding 'sap.ui.layout.Grid' as a content of VerticalLayout, so I solved the asked problem using 'attachBrowserEvent'
Below is the snippet-

```
var oGrid = new sap.ui.layout.Grid({
            hSpacing: 1,
            vSpacing: 0.5,
            content: [ oFields ]
            }).attachBrowserEvent('mouseover', function(oEvent){
                  //to do code
            });
```